# Remove data from HashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have HashMap `HashMap<Integer, List<String>> storeR` and it stores `"22,name1,name2"`..but is there any way to remove `name1` from the `22`? i just want to remove only name 1 from 22. How do i do that.?I hope you can help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried looking into documentation of `HashMap` and `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the list out of your map and remove the element you want to have removed:

```
storeR.get(22).remove("name1");
```

If there is no key `22` in the map, or it's value is `null` this will throw a `NullPointerException`, though.

Answer (score 3):

Given the questions you've asked around this, you'd be better off using a third party library: [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface with various implementations - you'd probably want [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).

You can then just write:

```
multimap.remove(22, "name1");
```

If you *really* want to keep doing all the work manually yourself, you can call `get` on the map to return the list, and then `remove` on the list to remove the value. But you should consider whether you want to *also* remove the key entirely if you've removed the last value - and of course if you don't know whether the key already exists in the map, you need to only *conditionally* call `remove`...

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) in Guava is designed for the case.

See: 
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap